# dynamic change of the displayed HTML div class.

Tags: javascript

My html file looks like this:

```
<div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Work</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
</div>

    <div id="Home">
    <p>My content one</p>
    </div>

<div id="Work">
        <p>My content two</p>
        </div>
```

And I want always to display only one div id on my page.

If I press 'Home', display div id: Home.
Else I press a Work, display div id: Work.

I would like this change to be dynamic (without reloading the page) because then I want to add transition.

Comment: and what have you tried so far? your question is really broad....you should get familiar with frontend frameworks like Angular and its template engine https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Do you have any code demonstrating what you've tried? This can be solved  by assigning a css class on an onclick event

Comment: @Kyle, I had an idea to use toggleClass in jQuery, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: @messerbill I can not use frameworks yet, because I'm beginner and I can only coding in HTML5 and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said in my comment to your question i strongly recommend to use something like https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

But if you still want to solve it native you could do the following:

```
function changeMenuState(state) {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('content').length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('content')[i].style.visibility = "hidden"
  }
  document.getElementById(state).style.visibility = "visible"
}

document.getElementById('link1').addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeMenuState('Home')
})
document.getElementById('link2').addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeMenuState('Work')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xcqe323e/

Comment: if this solved your question please mark it with the green hook and let other users know that this is working ;)